# Doctrine 2: searching similar, yet different column data from two different entities in one query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I am making a library catalog system, and I have two entities, Books and Videos.  And in my app, they won't extend from a mapped superclass, because while they are similar, they're still different enough.  Books have one or many authors, a title, and a published date.  Videos have one or more directors, a title, and a release date.  I wanted to be able to search both books and videos by creator (which we define as book author or video director), title, and date (published date or release date), as well as limit the results to 10, 25, or 50.  Is this possible?

Comment: First please include your schema.

Second is you can probably do this in one table and have a flag as to wether its a book or video and be alot better off.

Then your view side of your code fills in the appropriate text such as "published on" or "released on". You can have a schema like title, originator, live_date, type (or isBook) i prefer type as you might add some other media type

Comment: @Shawn, this is a simplified example.  But let's say that they are still different entities and cannot have a mapped superclass b/c conforming all of the different, yet similar columns + the numerous null columns that would be needed for single table inheritance would make a mess just so i can satisfy this one query.

Comment: Why can't you use queryBuilder and join the tables on author to publisher name? even if you have objects created you should be able to bidirectional map your entities